# Matlab double summation of series

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use a function in Matlab which will give me the following equation:

[image]

The `x` and `a` values are in two matrices. I have tried almost everything, but cannot get the correct answer. Anyone who can help??

Thanks

Comment: Can you show examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried two for-loops, one for `i` and second for `j`, with a condition inside, for the delta?

Comment: The deltas matrix, a_i and a_j you have already at memory, don't you? You can do two loops as you say, it is probably not the optimal answer for matlab, but that's the way. Add the codes your tried and what went wrong on them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A and X are vectors of size n x 1, you could construct that expression by writing `transpose(X) * (sqrt(A * transpose(A)) .* (ones(n) - eye(n))) * X`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is

```
a = sqrt(ain);                  % ain is your input column vector
A = a*a.';
A = A-diag(diag(A));
aresult =   x.'*A*x             % x is your (other) input column vector
```